# How to make a request to delete a row in DB?

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5.3, delete-row

I have read everything on this topic - and still in a fog.

I made a CRUD functional, and the question is - how to test/ how to use delete or update functions?

In my routes.php there is a one string:

```
Route::resource('templates', 'Vendor\App\Controllers\TemplateController');
```

In controller `destroy` and `update` functions are implemented.

So i'm trying to test delete. When a send DELETE request - i've got a error

```
 RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST'))
```

As far as i googled, method must be `POST`, but one of the form fields - named `_method` must have the value `DELETE` So i use the postman for testing, and got the same error:

[image]

What am i doing wrong? how to make a delete request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the right request, but to the wrong URL. As noted in the [corresponding docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers), the URL for the `DELETE` request should be `/templates/{id}`. Try it eg. with `templates/1`